# Variable name as variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a question about using variables as variablename.
I have an array with database fieldnames as key and object properties as values
like this:

```
$properties = array("userid" => "user['userid']", "city" => "hometown");

foreach ($properties as $field => $property ) { 
  $value1 = $db->$field;
  $value2 = $obj->$property;
}
```

This works for the property hometown but doesn't work voor de property user['userid'].
What is the correct way to adress the property variable?
I also tried several things like:  ${property} or {$property} but without luck yet.

edit:
Thanks for all the responses! For now I'll stay with my original solution, I was wondering if there was a way, I don't have principal problems with the eval version, will keep it in mind!

```
 foreach ($fields as $field => $property ) {
        switch ($field) {
            case "userid":
                $newvalue = $this->user['userid'];
                $oldvalue = $original->user['userid'];
                break;
            // more cases ...
            default:
                $newvalue = $this->{$property};
                $oldvalue = $original->($property};
        } 
        ....
```

Comment: have you tried `"userid" => $user['userid'], ` ?

Comment: @RokKralj Calling each other plain stupid is not something that fits this site. Please don't act like a kid.

Comment: Well. Code is stupid. Guess I mistargeted.

Comment: Please refactor your code. What you're trying to do is not possible without getting your hands dirty. Don't use this is production code.

Comment: refactoring is propably the best option here. however, i found this interesting so i provided a proof of concept.

Comment: @Ruud If you have problem refactoring, open a new question, detail your problem and people might be able to help.

Comment: if `eval` is the answer, you're asking the wrong question. What are you using this for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, so I decided to comment on this problem. Kai (no offence :) provided you a solution which doesn't use eval, but at the cost of additional 12 or so lines of code, making the code no doubt slower and more complex. So I myself think that in this case, it is justified to use eval() call. Hovewer, that could be just me (I value clear and short code a lot).

But beware, if input is **coming from external sources**, then you should filter it.

```
$properties = array("userid" => "user['userid']", "city" => "hometown");

foreach ($properties as $field => $property ) { 
  $value1 = $db->$field;
  eval("\$value2=\$obj->$property;");
}
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but there is a nicer way. `eval` is justified in very rare cases.

Comment: Can you provide one? I believe this is the case where eval is justified.

Comment: provided one. :-P `eval()` is `evil()`

Comment: So are long, unnecessary blocks of code. Get it? This is the situation, where eval contributes a lot to code clarity and error free code, as properties are parsed as native PHP, and it IMO should be used with propper care.

Comment: Maybe I did not fully understand the question. I have seen no example of the object in question (property `user` is an array as it seems). In this case this cannot be solved without an ugly hack or an eval. Code needs to be refactored, neither is a maintainable solution.

Comment: @RokKralj `eval` never contributes to code clarity. This is only "acceptable" when you have to provide a solution very quickly and don't have time to refactor.

Comment: Eval never contributes to code clarity? Ha Ha. Take a 5 second look at my code and a 5 second look at Kaii's and tell me - which do you understand more?

Comment: in both cases the code would look like `get_var($varname)`. however, i'm not interested in discussion.

Comment: your problem that you can see only small part of the whole thing. you have found a solution for the small particular problem but you don't understand that this problem is architectural one, and with proper architecture you will need no such dirty workarounds at all.

Comment: I don't care. I haven't used eval **ever in my whole life**. Op has a problem to solve, you already suggested redesign, I'm just providing one of the possible solutions for the current situation. Architectural redesign can be expensive, maybe OP is aware of it, but just cannot afford it. Apparently, he was happy with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

if `$obj` is an object and has a field `$property`

`$obj->{$property}` should be working fine

also you can use the curly brackets with concatenated strings like:

```
$obj->{ "field_" . $field_name };
```

In your case `$property` is a string, so on the first iteration it will be `user['userid']`

**edit:** to make it 2 dimensional array `$properties` have to be defined like this:

```
$properties = array(
    'user' => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'username'
    ),
    'city' => 'hometown'
);
```

Comment: $obj->{$property} should be working fine,  it should but it doesn't!

Comment: @Ruud: resort to my solution.

Comment: The problem here is that he is using an array index, and this is not supported by the "variable variables" syntax of PHP. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have an array index there and this is not supported by the "variable variables" syntax of PHP.

I know this is kind of magic, but you *can* do this without the use of evil `eval()`.

Please note: **this is just a proof of concept to show that it's possible.**

What you really should to is **refactor your code in a way so that such a hack is not necessary**.

```
$bar = "hallo";
$foo['bar']['baz'] = "hallo2";

$properties = array('bar', "foo['bar']['baz']");

// DOES NOT WORK
foreach ($properties as $property)
        echo "$property = ", $$property, "\n";

/* Results in:
 * bar = hallo
 * foo['bar']['baz'] = PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo['bar']['baz'] in /tmp/test.php on line 8
 */

// DOES WORK
foreach ($properties as $property)
        echo "$property = ", get_var($property), "\n";

/* Results in:
 * bar = hallo
 * foo['bar']['baz'] = hallo2
 */

// dark magic starts here
function get_var($name) {
        if (strpos($name, '[') === false) {
                global $$name;
                return $$name;
        } else {
                // split variable name into array name and nested index segments
                preg_match_all("#[^\[\]\"']+#", $name, $parts);
                $parts = $parts[0];

                // get pointer to array and walk down to the desired (nested) index
                $varname = array_shift($parts);
                global $$varname;
                $pointer =& $$varname;
                foreach ($parts as $index) {
                        $pointer =& $pointer[$index];
                }
                return $pointer;
        }
}
```

Comment: at least it's not prone to code injection. please explain why this is more evil.