# Variable array names

Tags: php, arrays

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

This appears when I try to find a array key by using variable array name:

```
class FOO {
    protected $arr = array();
    function bar(){
        $aaaaaaaaaaaa = 'arr';
        $this->$aaaaaaaaaaaa[$somekey]; // <-- error
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I do this with variable array names?

Comment: see related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374292/variable-name-as-variable

Comment: ok edited i hope its clear now

Comment: i edited my answer, but NO, it's far from clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MarcinJuraszek's right, when you assign `$arr` the second time it's no longer an array.

Anyway, I believe this code does what you intend to

```
<?php
class foo
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        $name = 'arr';
        $this->{$name} = array('Hello world!');
        echo $this->{$name}[0];
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$obj->doStuff();
```

Answer (score 2):

After that part of code:

```
$arr = 'arr';
```

$arr is no more an array. It's just a variable containing 'arr' string. So you can't access it as by key.

You should read information from [PHP: Arrays - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: ok i know that :) '...' is where the property declarations end and methods start..

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->{$arr}[$somekey]
```

is what you want (provided that you actually assign array to `$this->arr`, not just `$arr` that you reassign later.

Answer (score 2):

`$arr` is not an array. You first created one but then it's getting a string variable here: `$arr = 'arr';`.

This is correct:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 'arr';
$somekey = 0;

$this->$arr[$somekey]
```

Answer (score 2):

you are first defining $arr as an array, then you are OVER-writing its definition with a string. instead, maybe you wanted to add an element to the list:

```
$arr = array();

$somekey = 'mykey';
$arr[$somekey] = 'arrVal';

echo $arr[$somekey]
```

i think, i know what you want now:

a list of arrays...

```
$arr = array():
$arr['aaaaaaaaaa'] = array();
$arr['aaaaaaaaaa'][$somekey] = 'arrVal';

echo $arr['aaaaaaaaaaa'][$somekey]
```

and what's up with all the screaming?

Answer (score 1):

After say

```
$arr = 'arr';
```

Variable $arr is no longer a variable, may be what you want to do is add that value to the array in which case try the following:

```
arr.push('arr');
```

Then it should work I think